# My Header on linked sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrolling(fixed) header on my site, what I want to do is when users click on links from my website to other sites I want to continue showing my header at the top of that web page [Such As](http://www.solarmovie.so/link/play/1154210/). That continues to show the solarmovie header but the website has changed to filenuke. I have tried iframe but it's not working correctly, and that maybe because my links are pulled from the database and not actually links I can add to the html such as the following is how my links looks:

```
    <div class="span4">
' . anchor('watchmovies/go/'.$l->linkID, $l->link_title) . '
</div>
```

Now when someone click the links that shows on my site, it will go directly to the website, but I want to have my header on the site that visitors goes to. Is there a way?

Comment: Removed PHP tag, this question includes no reference/visual php

Comment: Only if you link to a URL on your own site, and on that page, show the external site in an iframe. Even then, the external site is able to prevent this (known as 'framebusting').

Comment: Why do you even want to do this; Let people leave your site when they decide they want to.

Comment: why is iframe not working correctly?